# Why is the Cholesky power iteration valid?

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra, cholesky-decomposition

Another user [claimed](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1244623) he/she could show the same iteration is well-defined if $A$ is 2-by-2 SPD. How can I show that this iteration method is well-defined for a SPD $A$ **of any size**? More specifically, how can we show (1) every $A_k$ in this iteration is SPD and (2) every $A_k$ can be uniquely determined by this iteration? Thanks in advance.